# How to stop MS Office from hijacking my spacebar?

Tags: macos, microsoft-office, adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

By company mandate I installed Microsoft Office. As soon as I launched Outlook I noticed I couldn't use Spacebar in Photoshop to pan around an image with the Hand Tool anymore.

I have observed this problem with Outlook + Photoshop, but from what I've read in [this thread](https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator/spacebar-not-working-as-quick-hand-tool-on-mac-adobe-illustrator/m-p/10878044) and others, other Office apps such as Excel cause the same problem. And other Adobe apps such as Illustrator are also affected by it. "Close Outlook" seems to be the consensus "solution", but it's not much of a solution if I need to use the Office apps regularly.

Why developers have the nerve to meddle with the shortcuts of other applications is incomprehensible...

<sup>Although I suppose with Microsoft, no amount of wackness should shock me.</sup>

Is there a setting or something I can change to fix this, or am I going to have to leave Outlook closed most of the time?

Details:

- Microsoft Outlook for Mac (16.49)
- Adobe Photoshop 2021 (22.4.1)
- macOS Mojave (10.14.6)

Comment: Not a solution, perhaps a workround - use Outlook on the web instead. https://outlook.office.com/ [I don't actually have Office installed but must occasionally access it - that's how I do it]

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks, I will consider that as an option if no solutions can be found with the app.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just outlook, so far Excel and powerpoint too. I have to close those programs to use illustrator and photoshop spacebar.

Hope somebody has a solution.

Mac Ventura MS Office 2021.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1190144)